# Problems retrieving nested data from json

Tags: javascript, html, json, loops, nested

I am working on a small project and i made the following json data -> http://www.smartbustracking.be/json/data.json.

The following below code loops through my json data. I can successfully read the "busuur" but not the nesting of bussen.

Am i writing the code wrong of is my syntax not correct

```
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $.getJSON("http://www.smartbustracking.be/json/data.json", function(json){
                //$each is the same as for loop
                $.each(json, function(i, field) {
                    $("#bussen").append("<li><a href='javascript: World.onPoiDetailMoreButtonClicked();'>" + field.busuur  + " " + field.bussen.busnummer + ": " + field.bussen.busnaam + "</><li><br />");
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Just a note about JSON vs objects: JSON is a string and not an object hence its abbreviation of **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. What you have after retrieving it is colloquially referred to as a POJO or **P**lain **O**ld **J**avascript **O**bject. They are different. The former is a data exchange format similar to YAML or XML while the latter is an actual object with properties and values.

Comment: unrelated comment: the `</>` might be a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bussen` is an array

```
"bussen":[{"busnummer":"530","busnaam":"test bus 1"},{"busnummer":"540","busnaam":"mechelen"}]
```

You need to iterate through its items

For example  , to get only the *first* item you'd do :

```
 $.each(json, function(i, field) {
                    $("#bussen").append("<li>..." + field.bussen[0].busnummer + ": " + field.bussen[0].busnaam + "</><li><br />");
                });
```

You *might(!)* want to do [this](http://jsbin.com/xiwiziziwe/2/edit)  :

```
  $.each(json, function(i, field) {
                  var a="<li><a href='javascript: World.onPoiDetailMoreButtonClicked();'>" + field.busuur  + " " ;
                  var b='';

                     for (var k=0;k<field.bussen.length;k++)
                               b+=   field.bussen[k].busnummer + ": " +field.bussen[k].busnaam ;

               console.log(a+b+ "</><li><br />");    
                });
```

Comment: yes that fixed the issue but bussen has two items and if i do -> $.each(json, function(i, field) {
                    $("#bussen").append("<li>..." + field.bussen[i].busnummer + ": " + field.bussen[i].busnaam + "</><li><br />");
                });   it only shows one item. how to show multiple?

Comment: @GY22 see my _might_ section

Comment: if you surf to the following url -> http://www.smartbustracking.be/json/data.json you will see that i am trying to do a double nesting with the previous code from above but with my second for loop i get the error that my length is undefined 

see this link for code - > http://plnkr.co/edit/Xf1VbvX1wWHRAkQsNWEA?p=preview

Comment: last print screen you showed i don't fully understand line 11. is it possible to show the full line of the code. Thanks in advance